# LINQ to SQL value BETWEEN two double values

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using LINQ to SQL to query my database, I have a query very similar to this:

```
var result = from db.MyTable.Where(d => (double)d.Price >= minValue)
```

I need the where clause to have a `d.Proce >= minValue`, and `d.Price =< maxValue` (like a T-SQL `BETWEEN` clause).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

How about this:

```
var result = from db.MyTable.Where(d => (double)d.Price >= minValue 
                                         && (double)d.Price <= maxValue)
```

Answer (score 7):

Just for completeness; if you are building a query based on different inputs you can compose it with successive `Where` calls:

```
IQueryable<SomeType> query = db.MyTable;
if(minValue != null) // a Nullable<double>
{
    var actualMin = minValue.Value;
    query = query.Where(d => (double) d.Price >= actualMin);
}
if(maxValue != null) // a Nullable<double>
{
    var actualMax = maxValue.Value;
    query = query.Where(d => (double) d.Price <= actualMax);
}
// keep working with "query", for example, query.ToList();
```

Comment: For the sake of code legibility, maybe you want to use .HasValue property on these nullable types.

Comment: @Bruno meh, if you think of them as nullable types, then to me comparing to null is more natural, and compares well to testing reference types.

Answer (score 0):

With the introduction of the [INumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumber-1?view=net-7.0) interface, you can create a simple abstraction that would work for most numerical types:

```cs
static bool Between<T>(T value, T min, T max) where T : INumber<T>
{
      return value >= min && value <= max;
}
```

It will look cleaner and be clearer IMO

```cs
var result = from db.MyTable.Where(Between(d.Price, minValue, maxValue))
```